# Creating a Hyper-V Vagrant box from a vhdx

Tags: hyper-v, vagrant, packer

i have a vhdx, i want to create a vagrant box from it. this is my vhdx[image]

after i create vagrant box and vagrant file from that box how do i create the hyper-v virtual machine from it? how do i **change the machine name** while virtual machine startup(after i run "Vagrant up"). Because if there are 2 machines in same name it can occur conflicts to avoid that need to have a different name.

Comment: Is it deploying? What happens after `vagrant up`? Did you do `vagrant ssh` after? Am I in the same file system as you?

Comment: i didn't create vagrant box from vhdx, i want to know how to do that as well